# DirectX-11 Instance Buffer returns E_INVALID_ARGS

Tags: directx-11

folks. I'm at the point where I'm starting to add in instancing to my game engine. This is a generic function I made so I could pass in an instance buffer pointer and some matrices, along with a list of the instances to draw. However, in its first loop, the buffer is NULL, so it tries to initialize it, but it fails with HR = E_INVALID_ARGS. I'm not exactly sure what part of the arguments are invalid.

The goal is to pass two 4X4 matrices in the form of XMFLOAT4X4 per instance.

The "sizeofXMFLOAT4X4" variable is just a sanity check to see how many bytes it reads as (64, 4bytes * 4floats/vec * 4 vec = 64).

If anyone can spot what might be going wrong here and could point it out, I'd appreciate it greatly. Let me know if you need additional information. Thanks.

```
void StaticSceneryListClass::UpdateInstanceBuffer(ID3D11Buffer *pInstanceBuffer, XMFLOAT4X4 VPMat, XMFLOAT4X4 tileMat,  vector<StaticSceneryStruct> culledInstanceList)
{
//Pass this the buffer you want to update, the VPMat for the frame, and a list of instances to draw and it will fill the buffer with the stuff and things. 
//If the buffer is not initialized yet, it will be initialized too.

//first, create the data needed.
vector<XMFLOAT4X4> instanceMats;

for (int i = 0; i < culledInstanceList.size(); i++)
{
    XMFLOAT4X4 WorldMat = xmCon->MatTranspose(xmCon->MatMultiply(culledInstanceList[i].worldMat, tileMat));
    XMFLOAT4X4 WVP = xmCon->MatTranspose(xmCon->MatMultiply(WorldMat, VPMat));
    instanceMats.push_back(WVP);
    instanceMats.push_back(WorldMat);
}

if (pInstanceBuffer == NULL)
{
    //buffer not initialized yet, initialize it.
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC instBuffDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&instBuffDesc, sizeof(instBuffDesc));
    sizeofXMFLOAT4X4 = sizeof(XMFLOAT4X4);
    instBuffDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    instBuffDesc.ByteWidth = sizeofXMFLOAT4X4 * 2 * culledInstanceList.size();
    instBuffDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    instBuffDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    instBuffDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA instData;
    ZeroMemory(&instData, sizeof(instData));

    instData.pSysMem = &instanceMats[0];
    HRESULT hr = graphicsPointers.pdev->CreateBuffer(&instBuffDesc, &instData, &pInstanceBuffer);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        //Fails here with E_INVALID_ARG
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to create instance buffer!", "StaticSceneryList", MB_OK);
    }
}
else
{
    //buffer already initialized, need to use resource may and unmap.
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    ZeroMemory(&mappedResource, sizeof(D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE));

    //  Disable GPU access to the vertex buffer data.
    graphicsPointers.pdevcon->Map(pInstanceBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
    //  Update the vertex buffer here.
    memcpy(mappedResource.pData, &instanceMats[0], sizeof(XMFLOAT4X4) * 2 * culledInstanceList.size());
    //  Reenable GPU access to the vertex buffer data.
    graphicsPointers.pdevcon->Unmap(pInstanceBuffer, 0);
}
```

UPDATE1: 12/2/2017 2:02 CST
I've been running various debugging tests this morning with interesting results. I tried isolating the issue and found that passing in null for data or a fresh local pointer for the buffer did nothing. I turned on the debug layer and it is giving me no output for the create buffer statement. I tried playing with the params of the buffer description to see what it would do and those gave me an error. I added a catch for if the culled list is size 0 and even if it isn't a multiple of 16. That got it to pass occasionally, but it has never actually produced a working buffer. In fact, it still usually fails with... S_OK?? FAILED(hr) is dropping with an HR of S_OK, which doesn't make a lot of sense. When I look at the memory value of the buffer pointer, it goes from null to having an address, but it isn't being caught by a "if not null, release and set to null" block.

The interesting side effect of this is that it is causing a huge memory leak of sorts. The process memory climbs at a near linear rate to over 3gb in about 10 seconds (I close the program at that point, it still is very responsive).

Of course, I also seem to get the occasional pass, which then never seems to stick because the code for if the buffer is already initialized has yet to trigger.

Here is the current updated code:

```
void StaticSceneryListClass::UpdateInstanceBuffer(ID3D11Buffer *pInstanceBuffer, XMFLOAT4X4 VPMat, XMFLOAT4X4 tileMat, vector<StaticSceneryStruct> culledInstanceList)
{
//Pass this the buffer you want to update, the VPMat for the frame, and a list of instances to draw and it will fill the buffer with the stuff and things. 
//If the buffer is not initialized yet, it will be initialized too.

//Skip this process if there aren't any instances to draw
if (culledInstanceList.size() > 0)
{
    //first, create the data needed.
    vector<XMFLOAT4X4> instanceMats;
    for (int i = 0; i < culledInstanceList.size(); i++)
    {
        XMFLOAT4X4 WorldMat = xmCon->MatTranspose(xmCon->MatMultiply(culledInstanceList[i].worldMat, tileMat));
        XMFLOAT4X4 WVP = xmCon->MatTranspose(xmCon->MatMultiply(WorldMat, VPMat));
        instanceMats.push_back(WVP);
        instanceMats.push_back(WorldMat);
    }

    if (pInstanceBuffer == NULL)
    {
        //buffer not initialized yet, initialize it.
        D3D11_BUFFER_DESC instBuffDesc;
        ZeroMemory(&instBuffDesc, sizeof(instBuffDesc));
        bytewidth = sizeof(XMFLOAT4X4) * 2 * culledInstanceList.size();
        if (bytewidth % 16 != 0)
        {
            //hasn't fallen into here yet, which makes sense.
            MessageBox(NULL, "Instance Buffer Byte Width Not a multiple of 16", "StaticSceneryList", MB_OK);
        }

        instBuffDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
        instBuffDesc.ByteWidth =  bytewidth;
        instBuffDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
        instBuffDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
        instBuffDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

        D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA instData;
        ZeroMemory(&instData, sizeof(instData));

        instData.pSysMem = &instanceMats[0];

        HRESULT hr = graphicsPointers.pdev->CreateBuffer(&instBuffDesc, &instData, &pInstanceBuffer);
        //HRESULT hr = graphicsPointers.pdev->CreateBuffer(&instBuffDesc, &instData, &debugInstanceBuffer); //DEBUG
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            //Fails here with S_OK lulwut
            MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to create instance buffer!", "StaticSceneryList", MB_OK);
            if (pInstanceBuffer != NULL)
            {
               //This doesn't seem to trigger even though the address is not 0x0000etc
                pInstanceBuffer->Release();
                pInstanceBuffer = NULL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //occasionally gets here but it doesn't seem to stick
            MessageBox(NULL, "Successfully created instance buffer.", "StaticSceneryList", MB_OK);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //never seems to get to here.
        //buffer already initialized, need to use resource may and unmap.
        D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
        ZeroMemory(&mappedResource, sizeof(D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE));

        //  Disable GPU access to the vertex buffer data.
        graphicsPointers.pdevcon->Map(pInstanceBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
        //  Update the vertex buffer here.
        memcpy(mappedResource.pData, &instanceMats[0], sizeof(XMFLOAT4X4) * 2 * culledInstanceList.size());
        //  Reenable GPU access to the vertex buffer data.
        graphicsPointers.pdevcon->Unmap(pInstanceBuffer, 0);
    }
}//if there is anything to draw
```

Comment: Turn on the [debug device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/) and look for diagnostic output.

Comment: @Chuck Walbourn Hi, Chuck. Please see edited main post, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bunch more testing with no luck, I moved the code out into where this function was being called and wrote it in terms of the objects directly instead of indirectly and I got it working, at least with a default buffer. I have no idea WHY but there was something wonky going on with the passing of the pointer that would cause it to end up null by the time it got back out of the function call.

Also, side note, when you declare the series of four R32B32G32A32_FLOAT vectors in your input layout and then pull them in as four float4s in your vertex shader and then combine them using float4x4(vec1, vec2, vec3, vec4), you DON'T transpose an XMFLOAT4X4 before putting it into the buffer data!

Comment: Do you mean you are writing the objects into a memory buffer by looping through your list?

Also, you can set your matrix to row major to avoid the transpose (I assume you are using column major)

Comment: Hi, Ernie. I loop through the list of "instance structs" to grab the Local space matrix of each one. I multiply the local space matrix by a tile space matrix to generate the world space matrix. I save the world matrix but also use it to generate the WVP matrix. I then store the WVP matrix and the world matrix in a vector. By the end of the loop, the vector contains the WVP and world matrix for each instance. I then set the vector as the data for the instance buffer. When I say directly vs indirectly, I mean I had been passing the instance buffer pointer to a function and now

Comment: I operate on the pointer directly from the structure that contains it. My current setup seems to be running great. The world is getting amazing now that I have forest and bushes/grass stubs as far as the farplane can see.

Comment: Yah.  Similar what I've been doing.   Was wondering if your standard vector list was causing issues but checked at the memory ous contiguous from element 0. Gl.